# Memory location for a pointer passed in a function gets deleted

Tags: c++, function, pointers, null

**Question:** I can't seem to set a pointer to an address that was created inside of a function. It always gets set to Null, how do I fix this?

**Problem:** I believe the problem is caused by the variable being created inside of another function. What's happening is that after the function executes, the pointer is set to NULL again.

**Code:**

```
void listAdd(int *list, int &length) {

    int* tempList = new int[ length + 1 ];
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i ++ )
    {
        (tempList)[ i ] = (list)[ i ];
    }

    cout << " Previous adress: " << hex << list << endl;
    if ( list != NULL )
        delete[] list;

    list = new int[ length + 1 ];
    cout << " New address: " << hex << list << endl << dec;

    for( int i = 0; i < length; i ++ )
    {
        (list)[ i ] = (tempList)[ i ];
    }

    delete[] tempList;

    cout << " Enter a number: ";
    int stored = 0;
    cin >> stored;
    (list)[length -1] = stored;

    length ++;
    cout << " Length: " << length << "\n";


    cout << " value at array point 0: "  << (list)[length -1];
    cout << "\n retry " << (list)[length-1] <<"\n";

    cout << "\n \n \n This is pointing to 0x" << hex << list << '\n' << flush;
}
```

Comment: How is `list` passed into `listAdd()`? How is it declared?

Comment: @kfsone Thanks, I couldn't find anything similar and I believe that's what my problem is.

Comment: His subject line was awful, but it gives a very succinct example of the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you would like the changes to `list` to be valid after the function returned: since `list` is passed by value, the object manipulated inside the function happens to be a copy of the one you passed in. You probably either want to pass the object by reference, i.e.:

```
void listAdd(int*& list, int &length) {
    // ...
}
```

... or return the result

```
int* listAdd(int* list, int& length) {
    // ...
    return list;
}

list = listAdd(list, length);
```

Well, realistically, you really really want to encapsulate the objects in a class or just use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Wow, great answer and solution to my problem. This was exactly what I was looking for. I tried referencing the pointer -- but I didn't realize that you had to mention the integer was an actual pointer. Thanks a lot!